# Site columns pages (mngfield.aspx) loads very slow (more than 3 minutes)

Tags: 2013, site-column

Site columns page of subsites on my production farm loads very long. It takes not less than 3 minutes to load it. It is happening for all subsites, whereas Site columns page of the site collection works well.

Also it is impossible to open Site Columns of any subsites using SPD (I am getting: "An error occurred while trying to fetch data from your SharePoint site").

The following PowerShell cmdlet for my subsite runs very fast:

```
$web.AvailableFields.SchemaXml | Out-File c:\temp\fields.txt
```

In the ULS I can see a lot of stings (more than 3000) like:

```
[Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 05/29/2013 08:20:43.03, Original Level: Verbose] SQL connection time: 0.0594349281822131
[Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: VerboseEx] SQL IO Statistics: Procedure {0}, {1}
[Forced due to logging gap, cached @ 05/29/2013 08:20:45.05, Original Level: VerboseEx] SPRequestParameters: AppPrincipal={0}, UserName={1}, UserKye={2}, RoleCount={3}, Roles={4}
[Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: VerboseEx] Reverting to process identity
```

And right before loading completes I can see that some resources were not disposed during the request:

```
Leaving Monitored Scope (SharePointForm Control Render). Execution Time=168222,944536247
An SPRequest object was not disposed before the end of this thread.  To avoid wasting system resources, dispose of this object or its parent (such as an SPSite or SPWeb) as soon as you are done using it.  This object will now be disposed.  Allocation Id: {1695290C-4861-4C41-80F5-DC2BDFFF88C9}  
This SPRequest was allocated at    at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest..ctor()     at 
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.CreateSPRequestAndSetIdentity(SPSite site, String name, Boolean bNotGlobalAdminCode, String strUrl, Boolean bNotAddToContext, Byte[] UserToken, SPAppPrincipalToken appPrincipalToken, String userName, Boolean bIgnoreTokenTimeout, Boolean bAsAnonymous)     at 
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitializeSPRequest()     at 
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.EnsureSPRequest()     at 
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.InitWebPublic()     at 
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_LanguageCulture()     at 
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.get_Title()     at 
Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.FieldListRenderer.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)     at
System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)     at 
System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at 
System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)     at 
System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at 
Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.AjaxDelta.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter output)     at 
System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at 
System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at 
Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.AjaxDelta.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at 
System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)     at 
System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at 
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at 
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at 
Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SharePointForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)     at 
System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)     at 
System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at 
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at 
System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)     at 
System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at 
System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)     at 
System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)     at 
Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at 
System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at 
Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DeltaPage.RenderToBase(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DeltaPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at 
Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.UnsecuredLayoutsPageBase.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)     at 
System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)     at 
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at 
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at 
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at 
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at 
System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at 
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)     at 
System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)     at 
System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)     at 
System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at 
System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at 
System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at 
System.Web.Hosting.UnsafeIISMethods.MgdIndicateCompletion(IntPtr pHandler, RequestNotificationStatus& notificationStatus)     at 
System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)     at 
System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, Int32 flags)
```

I have tried a lot of different things, but can't make it work for about a week already.

**Does anybody have any ideas what can be cause of this issue or what can I try for troubleshooting?**

Every suggestion is very appreciated as I ran out of ideas.

UPDATE1: Even subsites which have no site columns misbehave. Also, it seems that every another call to Site Columns page takes longer and longer.

Comment: Hi Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

We are facing the same issues. I have done some more research on this. It seems that some SQL queries run a lot when you request the site columns page in a subsite. I did the following on a test farm, since I'm poking around a bit in databases (which you should be carefull with).

Step 1: clear DB stats.

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS
```

Step 2: run the following query.

```
SELECT last_execution_time, execution_count,[text]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(deqs.sql_handle) AS dest
where dbid = (select database_id from sys.databases where name = 'WSS_Content_Intranet')
ORDER BY deqs.execution_count DESC
```

change your DB name here to whatever content db you are having the issue on. 
the results should be pretty empty. 
now, request the site columns page in a subsite. When it is finished loading, run the above query again.

I get the following result (I did remove the text column here from the query)

```
last_execution_time execution_count
2014-07-15 15:27:26.357 11340
2014-07-15 15:27:26.357 5670
2014-07-15 15:27:26.357 5670
2014-07-15 15:27:26.357 5670
2014-07-15 15:27:26.317 5668
2014-07-15 15:27:26.357 5668
2014-07-15 15:27:26.253 5666
```

Request the page again from the root site;

```
2014-07-15 15:28:46.890 11348
2014-07-15 15:28:46.887 5674
2014-07-15 15:28:46.887 5674
2014-07-15 15:28:46.887 5674
2014-07-15 15:28:46.887 5670
2014-07-15 15:28:46.887 5670
2014-07-15 15:28:46.417 5667
```

number up a bit, but not much. request it again from the subsite.

```
2014-07-15 15:29:59.713 22688
2014-07-15 15:29:59.710 11344
2014-07-15 15:29:59.713 11344
2014-07-15 15:29:59.710 11344
2014-07-15 15:29:59.710 11338
2014-07-15 15:29:59.710 11338
2014-07-15 15:29:59.570 11333
```

You see that numbers have almost doubled! You can actually see the numbers climbing fast when you run the SQL query while the page is loading.

Doesn't seem normal those queries get run that much to just get one page, but I have seen this now on 4 environments. Maybe time to call MS support :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have seen this post but it talks about a similar issue. Their problem was a third party application. Since we are not running any third party apps it didn't apply to us. We are still looking for a solution.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadminlegacy/thread/d9a3963d-4edf-4173-8733-549a27cbc762

Answer (score 0):

I recently hit the same issue which prevented me from adding an association column to a reusable workflow.

As with Mikhail and Thijs I checked and tried many things, including rebooting the SharePoint servers.

Deciding that the problem was SQL-related I decided to restart the SQL server. While this is not an ideal solution it does resolve the problem. At least for a while.